# How to get the data the user has input from a datagridview in winForm c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have an empty datagridview which I am using to collect data from the user. When the user moves onto the next tab I want to save the data entered. But according to the datagridview there is no rows. Yet when I go back to that tab the data still there.

I've tried this..

```
int i_rows = dataGridView1.RowCount;
for (int i = 0; i < i_rows; i++)
{
  var colValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

and this..

```
foreach (DataRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  var colValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

And I added an event to when UserAddRow which is triggered but still no rows in the dataGridView.

Comment: Do you have an object that each `DataRow` maps to?

Comment: no. they no rows when first loaded.

Comment: I understand that the rows are empty and the user enters some data, but what is the significance of the data row? What does it mean to you in English(not code)? I ask this, because I would think that you would populate the object then send it to the database.

Comment: a datarow is a row in the gridView. The rowCount is always 0 so don't get to populate anything.

Comment: Make sure you're adding the row. I assume there's an "add" button. But it sounds like you're handling a tab-out (or other) event before the row is added.

Comment: no there's no add button. How do I get what the user has inputted to add it?

Comment: Did you set the `DataSource` property of the grid ?

Comment: no. what would it be set to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "CellValueChanged" event instead of "UserAddRow" event.

The UserAddRow event is triggered when the last row goes into edit mode. At this point the cells in the last row hasn't registered any value, the edited cell register the value when the cell value changed event is triggered. If you use the "CellValuechanged" event it is most likely that you will get the value of the cell.

Comment: What do I put in the CellValueChanged event to make it add to the DataGridView?

Comment: The CellValueChanged event trigger at the end of user input to the cell. You can use this event to save the data that user just entered.